# Java - Function "insert" for generic implements

Tags: java, function, generics, insert

```
public interface IGenericList<T> {
    void insert(T element);
    void println();

}


public class GenericList<T> implements IGenericList<T> {

    private T param;

    public GenericList(T rootValue) {
        param = rootValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(T element) {
        param = param + element; //error "Operator + cannot be applied to 'T', 'T'
    }
    @Override
    public void println() {
        System.out.println(param);
    }
}
```

How can I implement that function? "insert"
I'm a beginner and that's all I'm given in the problem

Comment: You will have to have something resembling an actual list in there.  Right now you just have space for one element; you can't insert anything with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for what you need IGenericList, because List interface is already generic and all implementations, but I don't know all business aspects.
For inserting some data you need proper data structure, the classic data structure for that is array. I wrote common logic for array field type in generic style.

```
public interface IGenericList<T> {
        void insert(int index, T element);

        void append(T element);

        void println();
    }

    public static class GenericList<T> implements IGenericList<T> {

        private T[] params;

        public GenericList(T[] rootValue) {
            this.params = rootValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void insert(int index, T element) {
            if(index > params.length) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            params[index] = element;
        }

        @Override
        public void append(T element) {
            //find first null value or expand array and add value
        }

        @Override
        public void println() {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(params));
        }
    }
```